# Selenium WebDriver Wait until Click

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, webdriver

I have a problem with a code.

I need to wait for 3 seconds and then click the Follow button.

This code click the Follow button immediately when the website loads.

```
for follow in accounts_scrapped:
    driver.get(follow)

    try:
        follow_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text() = 'Follow']").click()
        print("found follow button")
        follow_button.click()
        print("followed")

    except:
        print("already followed this account. Going to next one")
        continue
```

Comment: use ```time.sleep(3)```?

Comment: didn't change anything.

Comment: you are clicking the button twice? ```follow_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text() = 'Follow']").click()``` has .click() at the end

Comment: and then you done ```follow_button.click()```

Comment: oops i put it by mistake. I want to click it one time, but not immediately .

Comment: @NikosLiolios What does `accounts_scrapped` contains?

Comment: After driver.get you should add some webdriver waits to make sure the page loads and the element can be found. If it's instagram it might be button instead of span.

Answer (score 1):

Debug your code  like this, this may help see where the problem is then

```
for follow in accounts_scrapped:
    driver.get(follow)
    try:
        follow_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text() = 'Follow']")
        time.sleep(3)
        print('0 seconds letf')
        follow_button.click()
        print("followed")
    except Exception as e :
        print(e)
        print("already followed this account. Going to next one")
        continue
```

`print(e)` will print the error

Comment: are you saying its not waiting 3 seconds? maybe somewhere else in your code you've clicked it?

Comment: I'am always getting the message "already followed this account. Going to next one"

Comment: that means the ```try``` block had an error so it moved to the ```except``` block

Comment: what's being printed out for ```print(e)```?

Comment: the time.sleep(3) as i understand waits 3 seconds until the next page appears. But in this case it clicks immediately the Follow button again when every page of the website appears.

Comment: ok i get this error "Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//span[text() = 'Follow']"}
  (Session info: chrome=87.0.4280.66)"

Comment: ```follow_button```  doesn't exist, it cant find that button, so probably somewhere earlier in your code you are pressing the follow button already

Comment: I can't find a command that is pressing the follow button. this is the only one.